# For a list of users and activity dates, how to find the earliest date?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a list of users and their activities, like this:

| user | date | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 1/1/21 | Hop |
| Dick | 1/2/21 | Skip |
| Harry | 2/2/21 | Jump |
| Tom | 1/3/21 | Skip |
| Dick | 1/4/21 | Jump |

I want to extract unique user names and the earliest activity date, to get a result like this:

| user | first activity |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 1/1/21 |
| Dick | 1/2/21 |
| Harry | 2/2/21 |

I know I can create an array of unique usernames like this:

`unique_users = user_actions[user].unique()`

But I don't know how to turn that array of unique usernames into a dataframe with the first action date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired result, you can do the following:

- Convert the `date` column to DateTime format for easy sorting and filtering
- Group by `user` and find the minimum date for each `user`

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
result = (
    df.groupby("user")["date"]
    .agg(first_activity="min")
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values("first_activity")
)
print(result)
```

Output:

```bash
    user first_activity
2    Tom     2021-01-01
0   Dick     2021-01-02
1  Harry     2021-02-02
```